# How to create a sympy equation for vectors?

Tags: vector, jupyter-notebook, symbols, equation, sympy

I am trying to display both sides of a vector equation.

I am able to `display()` the rhs of the equation but I am unable to define an equality `sympy.Eq(symbols("F_T"), F_Tx*N.x + F_Ty*N.y + F_Tz*N.z)` using vectors.  Ideally I would like F_T to its own symbol (for use in other equations) but creating a vector modifies the type() from "symbol" to "Vector".

Therefore I am unable to print the desired full equation (like a textbook might).  I am open to printing in LaTeX but I am uncertain how to combine my sympy expressions with created LaTeX.  Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

[image: Current]

I would like to be able to pretty-print: `F_T = F_Tx*N.x + F_Ty*N.y + F_Tz*N.z`

Answer (score 1):

I've been wondering about how to do the same thing. The following tips are not a perfect solution, but they may prove useful to someone.

```
def create_vector(sym, refFrame):
    unit_vectors = refFrame.base_vectors()
    syms = sp.symbols(' '.join([sym + '_{' + str(ax) + '}' for ax in unit_vectors]))
    vector = reduce(add, [sym * unit for sym, unit in zip(syms, unit_vectors)])
    return (vector,) + syms
```

This function allows you to quickly create a vector with unresolved symbolic components, like so:

```
XYZ = CoordSys3D('XYZ', vector_names=('I', 'J', 'K'))
r_rel, r_rel_i, r_rel_j, r_Rel_k = create_vector('\mathbf{r_{rel}}', XYZ)

r_rel
```

Now, if you try to render this in Jupyter, you get the ugly component representation:

[image]

But, if you are prepared to be a bit hacky, you can work around this. The Zero vector stores it's own latex representation internally, as self._latex_form. The sympy latex 
printer determines if a vector is the zero vector by checking if expr == expr.zero.
We can abuse these and trick the latex printer into printing a nicer representation:

```
r_rel.zero = r_rel
r_rel._latex_form = '\mathbf{r_{rel}}'
r_rel
```

For which we get this prettier representation:

[image]

Admittedly, this could break things, and it will make you feel dirty. But it may help someone.

Comment: Well, this was a while ago, @Tinmarino, but I managed to dig out the notebook :-)

try this:


    from functools import reduce
    from operator import add
    import sympy as sp
    from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D, Cross
    sp.init_printing()

    XYZ = CoordSys3D('XYZ', vector_names=('I', 'J', 'K'))

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an equality to display: `eq = Eq(F_T, F_Tx*N.x ...)`. An equality is printed with an equals sign separating the lhs and rhs of the equality.